# Performing groupby function using two columns as parameters regardless of the order of the columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given the following dataframe:

```
Node_1 Node_2 Time
A      B      6
A      B      4
B      A      2
B      C      5
```

How can one obtain, using groupby or other methods, the dataframe as follows:

```
Node_1 Node_2 Mean_Time
A      B      4
B      C      5
```

The first row's Mean_Time being obtained by finding the average of all routes A->B and B->A, i.e. `(6 + 4 + 2)/3 = 4`

Comment: join the columns together and then perform the "mean" operation?

Answer (score 1):

You could sort each row of the `Node_1` and `Node_2` columns using [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html):

```
nodes = df.filter(regex='Node')
arr = np.sort(nodes.values, axis=1)
df.loc[:, nodes.columns] = arr
```

which results in `df` now looking like:

```
  Node_1 Node_2  Time
0      A      B     6
1      A      B     4
2      A      B     2
3      B      C     5
```

With the `Node` columns sorted, you can `groupby/agg` as usual:

```
result = df.groupby(cols).agg('mean').reset_index()
```

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {'Node_1': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B'},
 'Node_2': {0: 'B', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'C'},
 'Time': {0: 6, 1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 5}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
nodes = df.filter(regex='Node')
arr = np.sort(nodes.values, axis=1)
cols = nodes.columns.tolist()
df.loc[:, nodes.columns] = arr

result = df.groupby(cols).agg('mean').reset_index()
print(result)
```

yields

```
  Node_1 Node_2  Time
0      A      B     4
1      B      C     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Something in the lines of should give you the desired result... This got a lot uglier than it was :D

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Node_1': {0: 'A', 1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'B'},
 'Node_2': {0: 'B', 1: 'B', 2: 'A', 3: 'C'},
 'Time': {0: 6, 1: 4, 2: 2, 3: 5}}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create new column to group by
df["Node"] = df[["Node_1","Node_2"]].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)),axis=1)
# Create Mean_time column
df["Mean_time"] = df.groupby('Node').transform('mean')
# Drop duplicate rows and drop Node and Time columns
df = df.drop_duplicates("Node").drop(['Node','Time'],axis=1)

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
      Node_1 Node_2  Mean_time
0      A      B          4
3      B      C          5
```

An alternative would be to use:

```
df = (df.groupby('Node', as_index=False)
            .agg({'Node_1':lambda x: list(x)[0],
                  'Node_2':lambda x: list(x)[0],
                  'Time': np.mean})
            .drop('Node',axis=1))
```

Comment: @WeiErn I don't get it, this should work for names too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Anton! I intended for the capital letters to be placeholders for actual names of the nodes which may comprise of 1 or more word(s), such as "New York". 
I tried changing the code used to create the "Node" column to [sorted(x)] but it becomes a 2-D list. Is there anywhere I could make the column a list of two strings?

Comment: @WeiErn Share some sample data! :)

Comment: @WeiErn How about: `tuple(sorted(x))`, see above, You can get a list with `[sorted(i) for i in df[["Node_1","Node_2"]].values]`, but that's not something you groupby.